Solve $x^3-7x-6$ by Cardan's method
Find all integer roots of the polynomial $p(x)=x^3-7x-6$ by the Cardan's method.
I am struggling on this one, because I always end up on a negative square root, but since all roots $\in \mathbb{Z}$, that should not exist. I guess I am missing some part of the algorithm or miscalculating something.
Any help is welcome. Here is what I have done so far:
Change the variable $x=w+z$
$p(x)= (w+z)^3-7(w+z)-6=0$
$p(x)=w^3+z^3+(w+z)(3wz-7)-6=0$ Let $(3wz-7)=0 \Rightarrow w=7/3z $
$p(x) = (\frac{7}{3z})^3 + z^3 -6=0 $ Calculating the cubes and multiplying both sides by $(3z)^3$
$p(x)=27z^6-162z^3+343$ Using the quadratic formula
$z^3=\frac{162\pm\sqrt{162^2-4*27*343}}{54} = 3 \pm \frac{\sqrt{-10800}}{54} $

it has three real roots. This leads to  cube roots of imaginary numbers; called https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casus_irreducibilis

$x^3-7x-6=(x-3)(x+1)(x+2)$ by the rational root theorem. With Cardano, one obtains $x=3$, and then we can do a polynomial division by $(x-3)$ to obtain $(x+1)(x+2)$.

By the way it should be Cardano not Cardan.

But why use Cardano's method, when the rational root theorem is much easier here to apply. One can even guess the root $x=-1$ very easily and then divide.

You defined $x = w + z$, so when you substitute $w = \frac{7}{3z}$, then we have $x = z + \frac{7}{3z}$ and
$$p(x) = x^3 - 7x - 6 = \left(z + \frac{7}{3z}\right)^3 - 7\left(z + \frac{7}{3z}\right) - 6 = 27z^3 - 162 + \frac{343}{z^3}.$$
But when you solve the related polynomial
$$q(z) = 27z^6 - 162z^3 + 343,$$
this gives you $z$.  It doesn't give you $x$.  You have to then compute $x = z + \frac{7}{3z}$ for each root of $q$.
To this end,
$$z^3 = \frac{162 \pm \sqrt{162^2 - 4(27)(343)}}{2(27)} = 3 \pm \frac{10i}{3\sqrt{3}} = 3 \pm \frac{10\sqrt{3}}{9} i.$$
So we have to compute the cube root.  This is not a simple thing; it turns out that
$$z = \frac{9 \pm i \sqrt{3}}{6},$$
which you may verify by computing $z^3$.  Then we have
$$x = z + \frac{7}{3z} = 3,$$
after which you may compute the other two roots of $p$ by factorization.  How come we didn't see the other two roots when we solved for $z$?  That is because there are other cube roots of $3 \pm \frac{10\sqrt{3}}{9}i$ besides the one we found:
$$z = \frac{-3\pm 5\sqrt{3}i}{6}, \quad z = -1 + \frac{2\sqrt{3}}{3} i.$$  But again, finding these is not trivial.

I am looking for the integer roots.

@FernandoCavendish The answer above clearly states $x = 3$ is an integer root, after which I state that the other two roots can be obtained via factorization; or you may use the other two roots of $q(z)$ to compute the other two integer roots of $p(x)$.
